# Math - rectangle bounded box from another

Tags: math, rotation, trigonometry, rectangles, bounds

I have a Math issue. I'm trying to find the coordinates and size of a bounding rectangle knowing another bounding rectangle and a thickness...

I know everything about the WHITE rectangle (bounding box GREEN, size, rotation, position).

The difference between the BLACK and the WHITE rectangles is the thickness (T).
I want to find the size of the GREY rectangle (which is the bounding box of the BLACK rectangle).

So I know:

- x,y
- w,h
- T
- rot
- r1 (position and size)

I want to find r2 (the bounding box of the BLACK rectangle).

Thanks for your answers :) and your time !!!!

Link to a image describing what I said [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct in my understanding given (x,y) and w, h and rotation rot for the white rectangle then you can calculate the green rectangle.

The black rectangle has the same rotation rot as the white rectangle so presumably if you know (X,Y) and W and H for the black triangle you can use the same method to find the grey rectangle as you did to find the green from the white.

Consider the white and black rectangles before rotation, ie width is horizontal

The X=x-T, Y=y-T W=w+2T, H=h+2T, so now you have (X,Y) W, H and rot for black rectangle so can calculate the grey one.

EDIT

If (x,y) is after rotation, then start with the white rectangle with its width horizonal and the top left corner at (lx,ty)  it follows that the top left corner of the black rectangle is at (lx-T, ty-T) and its width W and Height H is given by W=w+2T H=h+2T.

Now whenever you rotate the white rectangle rotate the black rectangle by the same amount using the same centre of rotation. This gives you (x,y) for new coordinates of the top left corner of the white rectangle and (X,Y) as the new coordinates of the top left corner of the black rectangle from which you can calculate the bounding rectangles.

EDIT rotating (x,y) about (0,0) by angle theta, with (x,y) rotating to (lx,ty)

lx=xcos(theta)-ysin(theta)

ty=xsin(theta)+ycos(theta)

Comment: In fact the method I use to calculate the green rectangle for the grey one come from knowing the x,y after the rotation not the one before. If we have a rotation X=x-T does not works anymore, for example for rotation = 130 :(

Comment: Have added explanation of what to do when (x,y) is know after rotation. I was making the incorrect assumption that (x,y) was the centre of rotation.

Comment: Your solution implies that I calculate the X,Y of the black rectangle during the rotation. But I want a solution without rotating myself the white rectangle because in my case I have a graphical element (White rectangle) already created with the rotation of 40. So I'm not rotating anymore. The rectangle is already rotated.

Comment: Take the values of (x,y) and rotate about (0,0) by -40 (-angle already rotated) this gives (lx,ty). Calculate X,Y,W and H of black rectangle as stated and then rotate this by 40 (angle used in rotation) about (0,0) which will give you the black rectangle in the position you want. If you do not know how to rotate (x,y) about (0,0) I have added it.

Comment: That works perfectly !!! I used your method but rotating by center not by (0,0). Thanks a lots